# "Title" Attribute vs Link Anchor Text in SEO

Tags: seo, links, title-attribute

Both "title" attribute and link anchor text does provide positive influence to SEO.

Example:

```
<a href="www.companyA.com">Service Provided</a>
<a href="www.companyB.com" title="Service Provided">Company B</a>
```

But how much is the different of influence between two? Company A or B will have better position in SEO?

Comment: https://seo-gold.com/anchor-text/title-attribute-seo-test-of-text-links/ and  https://www.semrush.com/blog/what-is-anchor-text-and-how-can-i-optimize-it/ :May this helps you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting keywords in the `title` attribute doesn't give SEO value to the linked site and the page of the link. However, the anchor of a link gives SEO value to the linked site and the page of the link.

Consequently, regarding optimizing the SEO value of a link, keywords in the anchor needs to be seriously considered instead of the "title" attribute.

However, the "title" attribute of a link is important as well but for users, not SEO.